# How to remove duplicates in my query result?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-spatial

I wrote a query to find duplicate geometries. So the query returns sets of equal objects, but I need only one object from every group. I wonder if there is any kind of **query** to do so?

I tried various group by, rollup, cube, etc. Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

This is the query example:

```
select t1.id, t2.id
  from geom_table t1, geom_table t2
 where sdo_relate(t1.geometry,t2.geometry,'mask=equal') = 'TRUE'
   and t1.id != t2.id
```

And this is the query result:

[image]

In this example i have two sets of duplicated geometry: 4098967,4098968 and 
4098964, 4098965, 4098969.

So I need, for example, only 4098967 and 4098964.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `id` comparison:

```
select . . .
from geom_table t1 join
     geom_table t2
     on sdo_relate(t1.geometry,t2.geometry,'mask=equal') = 'TRUE' and
        t1.id < t2.id
```

Comment: This is closer, but i still have wrong result, ids: 4098964, 4098965, 4098967.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code:

```
select distinct t1.id,t2.id
from geom_table t1,geom_table t2
where sdo_relate(t1.geometry,t2.geometry,'mask=equal')= 'TRUE'
and t1.id != t2.id
```

The change is on **distinct** which removes any duplicates in the tuples returned by the query

Comment: Of course i tried distinct, but the question is not how to remove duplicate rows, but how to remove duplicate geometry from one set with different id.

Comment: Distinct will not work. The query returns both (a,b) and (b,a) as duplicates. You only want one of them. For that, change the query from `t1.id != t2.id` to `t1.id < t2.id` or `t1.id > t2.id`. And distinct is not needed.

Comment: To get just one of the `id` per identical couple, you can use `select least(t1.id,t2.id) as id`. But this still does not give the proper answer when more than two duplicates exist.

Comment: I'm looking at the proper way for doing this removal (I need it for another project). I will share what I come up with.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind if u need this soltion, i have pl/sql code.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind, where we can discuss this?